Azure AD, AuthenticationTicket Claims
I'm working on an ASP.NET web application on .NET 4.8, and I receive the task to implement Azure AD for this application.
I created this startup.cs:
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(ApplicationName.Startup))]

namespace ApplicationName
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAd:ClientId"],
                Authority = $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAd:Instance"]}{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAd:TenantId"]}",
                ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAd:ClientSecret"],
                RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAd:RedirectUri"],
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAd:PostLogoutRedirectUri"],
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Error/Errors?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = async context =>
                    {
                        var clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAd:ClientId"];
                        var clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAd:ClientSecret"];
                        var authority = $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAd:Instance"]}{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAd:TenantId"]}";
                        var RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureAd:RedirectUri"];

                        var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                            .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
                            .WithRedirectUri(RedirectUri)
                            .Build();

                        var result = await cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(new[] { "User.Read" }, context.Code).ExecuteAsync();

                        // Extrair as informações do usuário a partir do token recebido
                        var userClaims = result.ClaimsPrincipal.Claims;
                        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType)
                        identity.AddClaims(userClaims);

                        // Adiciona a nova identidade com as reivindicações ao ticket
                        context.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, context.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

And this part looks working good. The problem is, when I try to get the user's email in a controller, the claims are completely different from when I checked in the userClaims variable (startup.cs).
The controller code is this:
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> ActionName()
{
    var claimsPrincipal = HttpContext.User as ClaimsPrincipal;

    if (claimsPrincipal != null)
    {
        // Obter as informações da clain
        var userName = claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
        var userEmail = claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;

        // more code...
    }
}

I've checked all the claims inside claimsPrincipal, and they are completely different from the claims in Startup.cs.
I just want to get the email from the logged-in user.

The problem was in my Startup.cs. I was receiving the authentication token but was missing the configuration to save and manipulate it.
I just add the following code at the top of my startup configuration
 // Configuração de autenticação por cookie
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Login/Login"),
                LogoutPath = new PathString("/Login/Logout"),
                CookieName = "ApplicationNameAuthCookie"
            });
   


Well it is about how ASP.NET tries to map the token payload, for example if you use this jwt token into jwt.io website:
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiZW1haWwiOiJ0ZXN0IiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.UfsTz5sDPCcUqW8-DD9Oh5KhPU9ulPtYTGcxp-_XL_I

this is the payload:
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "email": "test",
  "iat": 1516239022
}

So the actual claims are name or email and the others but when ASP.NET authentication tries to validate the token it uses some standard values to map the claim name and uses ClaimTypes constants, for example:
name => http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name
email => http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress
Here are all the values for ClaimTypes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimtypes
No need to worry about the claim name this is the way ASP.NET parses the token and is part of the OpenId standard.
